# Parsing Response XML with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I want to read a response from a non-wsdl web service call using JAXB.
I am sending a POST request using HttpURLConnection, and getting a response.
My question is do I make an xml doc from the response stream, then use jaxb to make the java objects? Or, is it possible to use use jaxb on the fly with the response stream?
This will be a web application, and I will not be able to store a generated xml doc anywhere, so if i need to make an xml doc, how do i store it for jaxb to use, if I cannot do the jaxb on the fly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Unmarshaller.unmarshal`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshal%28java.io.InputStream%29) can take an InputStream, which would eliminated the need to parse it to an XML doc.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example:

```
String uri =
    "http://localhost:8080/CustomerService/rest/customers/1";
URL url = new URL(uri);
HttpURLConnection connection =
    (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");

JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
InputStream xml = connection.getInputStream();
Customer customer =
    (Customer) jc.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(xml);

connection.disconnect();
```

For more information see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-55.html